prove that the point where the gradient of a quadratic function is equal to 0 is always a maximum or minimum point
For context, I am an a level maths student going back through all the content on the course and trying to understand everything that was taught throughout the year with proofs or at the very least, a good intuitive understanding but I can't seem to manage to get round this one without just accepting that a parabola looks the way it does and always has an apex ; surely there must be a way of proving that the apex (ie. where gradient is 0) is always the maximum or minimum point of the curve.
Thanks for any help in advance

There are two ways. The easiest way is to change the quadratic function from the $ f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ form into $ f(x) = a(x-p)^2 + q $. From this point you consider two cases: $ a<0 $ and $ a >0 $. Then you use the fact, that for any $ x \in \mathbb{R}, x^2 \ge 0 $, which proves that $ f(x) $ has a extreme at $ x = p $. The other way is to naturally use derivatives, although it may be a little overkill. If you wish, I can post a full proof.

if you're willing to show the full proof with derivatives, please, go ahead. I knew the proof was blatantly obvious but just couldn't get it down. thanks though

Let $ f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, \ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} $.
Case 1. $ a > 0 $
We can easily see, that $ f'(x) = 2ax + b $ (using linearity of derivatives and power rule).
Now we set $ f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = \frac{-b}{2a} $.
Let $ \frac{-b}{2a}=p $. Then $ f(p \pm \epsilon) = a(p \pm \epsilon)^2 + b(p \pm \epsilon) + c = ap^2 \pm 2ap\epsilon + \epsilon^2 + bp \pm b\epsilon + c = f(p)\pm 2ap \epsilon + b \epsilon + \epsilon^2$ for some $ \epsilon > 0 $.
Now from the derivative expression we see that $ 2ap\epsilon \pm b\epsilon = \epsilon(2ap+b)=0 $ (character limit)

[...] Hence $ f(p \pm \epsilon) = f(p) + a\epsilon^2 \ge f(p) $, hence $ f(p) $ is a minimum, because $ a > 0 $.

Case 2. $ a < 0 $
We use the $ \epsilon $ as a parameter once again, since the derivative equality holds here too.
$ f(p \pm \epsilon) = ap^2 \pm 2ap\epsilon + a\epsilon^2 + bp \pm b\epsilon + c = f(p) \pm \epsilon (2ap + b) + a\epsilon^2 = f(p) + a\epsilon^2 \le f(p) $, because $a<0$. Hence $f(x)$ attains a maximum at $x=p$.
q.e.d.
